# Dragging UIView on touch not working when finger is on UIButton inside that View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I want to be able to move around `UIView` with finger.

Inside `UIView` is `UIButton`, when finger starts dragging from area inside view but outside of button everything works as expected, but when finger starts dragging from `UIButton` view is not moving.

So basiclly I need something like `delaysContentTouches` available for `UIScrollView`.

How can I stop `UIButton` from stealing touch? Note that I would like `UIButton` to be still clickable.

Sample code to represent the problem:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let testView = View(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 10.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
        testView.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(testView)

        let button = UIButton()
        testView.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("button", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .red

        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

class View: UIView {
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self)

        self.frame.origin.x += touchPoint.x
        self.frame.origin.y += touchPoint.y
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using touchesMoved. Use a pan gesture. Thats what they are for. Also, I was able to get button touches as well

```
@objc func panGestureHandler(panGesture recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

if let thisView = recognizer.view {

  if recognizer.state == .began {
    someCentre = thisView.center // store old button center
  } else if  recognizer.state == .failed || recognizer.state == .cancelled {
    thisView.center = someCentre! // restore button center
  } else {
    let location = recognizer.location(in: view) // get pan location
    thisView.center = location // set button to where finger is
  }
}}
```

In view did load -

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector(self.panGestureHandler(panGesture:)))
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
testView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
someCentre = testView.center
```

Comment: It works, thanks for helping, however still I don't understand why touchesMoved doesn't work in that case